# Firefox add's 2px padding in a submit button

Tags: css, firefox, button, submit, padding

Hi I seem to be having some problems with Firefox adding 2 extra pixels of padding in a submit button.I have tested this in chrome and IE9 and both browsers render the code ok,Firefox seems to be adding 2 pixel padding at the bottom to the submit button with the key background on the top-right corner.Here is the website:

[www.thanathos.host22.com](http://www.thanathos.host22.com/)

This is the code for the site:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.html">
               <input type="text" value="Username"/>
               <input type="text" value="Password"/>
               <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
               <img src="img/header/key.png" alt="" id="key"/>
      </form>

    header section form input{
        color:#b3aaaa;
        border:1px solid #cccccc;
        float: left;
        padding:5px 8px;
        margin-left: 6px;
    }
```

How can I correct this?

If there is no solution for this can anyone please provide me a solution in witch the input text is equal with input submit and the input text is center from top-bottom?

[image]

**EDIT:** I have checked this in another computer and it seems that Firefox renders this correctly I have encountered this type of problem before that the same browser version shows a website a bit different on different computers.Last time something similar happened in chrome.I never could solve this problem.

Anyone know why the same browser would render a page differently on different computers with the same screen size and resolution?

Comment: No padding in my case. I am using Firefox 15! :)

Comment: I am also using Firefox 15 and for some reason at the bottom I get two extra pixels of padding

Comment: Dude, a screenshot? With the firebug window, showing the layout?

Comment: Do you use something like normalize or reset.css to make all browsers to look the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having a problem like this. I then found this `CSS` thingy that solved the problem:

```
input::-moz-focus-inner { border:0; padding:0 }
```

This solution was given in a comment in this blog post:

[Bulletproof CSS input button heights](http://cbjdigital.com/blog/2010/08/bulletproof_css_input_button_heights)

As the post says: this happens because Firefox (User Agent) own `CSS` style uses `!important` and anything one tries to do to override the `CSS` property won't get applied.

Comment: THIS. Firefox-specific hidden padding on submit buttons must die.

Comment: And in 2016, still need this to fix it in Firefox! Add on: I found out in my scenario, setting `input { height: 100% }`, or just need `input::-moz-focus-inner { border:0;}` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

** I leave this here since I think it's useful anywhoo..**

in either case try accessing just the button and play around with the css for it:

```
input[type="submit"] {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay so there is a problem with your solution, since you're positioning the image above the button you'll make it harder to actually click the submit-button. If you hover the mouse over the key you'll see that it doesnt change to a pointer = not clickable.

I suggest that you remove the image-tag and instead use it as a background in your submit-button. Something like this:

```
input[type="submit"] {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  background: url(path-to-image);
  border: none;
  height: "img-height";
  width: "img-width";
}
```

If the size of the image is correct, also since you do seem to have some sort of background in the submit button allready. Id go with making an image that is the correct size which contains both the background and the key image (I hope this last sentence makes some sence).

Another possible problem could be that you have no text in your button, however the button should inherit the lineheight/font-size from earlier in the css and thus might expand the submit-button more. Try adding something like font-size: 1px or something.

Comment: this can not be the case because the image is positioned absolutely.Anyway I tested it but it did not work

Comment: Also, in your case set the border to: solid 1px #000 since that is what you use now, isn't it. :)

Comment: I already know about the image that is position on top and can not be clicked it will be corected on some point the problem is not related to that image I can asure you I have removed it and the problem still persists

Comment: if you have not read corectly my problem is that in firefox I get 2px padding at the bottom the rest of the browsers show this corectly only firefox ads 2 extra pixels.The image is not of importance in this case I know I have to modify the code and I will at some point

Comment: @user985482 True, I've updated my answer with something that might be a solution