# Invisible padding in input submit

Tags: firefox, css

I have two boxes. The first one contains simple text. The second one contains a submit input with no borders, paddings, margins.

So, why the input takes more height than the simple text?

I know that I can play with the padding and remove the box height, but for my purposes I need to set it a static height, and prepare this box to be reusable for both inputs and simple texts.

I have tried to play with `line-height` and `vertical-align` properties, without success.

**What is causing that extra `line-height`?**

There's an [example to play with it](http://jsfiddle.net/QfPGW/).

**Edit:** I recently see, that the issue is only with Firefox...

I think it could be for the `line-height` property in the Firefox CSS:

[image]

But... in first place I can't believe what my eyes are seeing. An !important in the internal browser stylesheet? That's normal? Could this be a possible answer?

[Similar question with the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288175/firefox-adds-2px-padding-in-a-submit-button?rq=1).
But the trick Leniel suggest doesn't work for me...

Comment: strange behavior. It displays fine in Chrome and IE, but not FF...

Comment: It doesn't appear to be line-height to me as it also creates space on the left and right which would not be line height.

Answer (score 1):

The extra padding is on your `.buttonarrownext` class.

**Fixed CSS Class:**

```
.buttonarrownext {
    cursor:pointer; 
    position:relative; 
    border-radius:4px; 
    text-align:center; 
    background:white; 
    border:1px solid red; 
    padding: 0px; /* changed the padding here */
    margin:0px auto; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfPGW/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks, but as I say, "I know that I can play with the padding", my question is why there is more padding in the second box. The padding is the same in both "buttonarrownext"... but the second is taller, even removing the padding (in FF).

Comment: @Arkana I see what you mean now...  I completely misunderstood your question.  That said, I can't find any documentation on it, but it would seem that firefox applies a default ammount of padding to input elements that can't be reset.  That's my only conclusion

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, it displays fine in IE and Chrome, but not FF. A quick solution is to replace the `input` with a `button`.

updated html would be:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="buttonarrownext">Siguiente</div>
  <div class="buttonarrownext"><button class="reset">Siguiente</button></div>
    </div>
```

There's no real difference as you can still fire a submit event with a click handler for the button... 
It will be interesting to find out why FireFox does this though...

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QfPGW/2/

Comment: I don't know if we can change the markup (we are using JSF Primefaces to do it), but it's a nice solution. If only I can find out WHY is this happen... thanks at all :)

Comment: another partial fix is to set a fixed height for div.buttonarrownext, but this introduces another problem with the text not being centered vertically - http://jsfiddle.net/QfPGW/3/ and with fixed text alignment - http://jsfiddle.net/QfPGW/4/

Comment: Yes, and it "cuts" the letters at bottom :( Firefox... I believed in you... tu quoque, fili mi.... :(